# Biographies comparing the personal and professional lives of various influential scientists/mathematicians?

Tags: biographical-details

There are many biographies that go into detail into the lives of a single, or maybe a couple of scientists.

I am wondering, is there a good book that does not focus on an individual, but explicitly takes theses individuals as examples, of the "typical" scientist, or looks at the various types of scientists?

Answer (score 5):

Not sure these exactly fit your needs, but I am reminded of:

- *Gindikin, Simon*, [**Tales of mathematicians and physicists. Transl. from the Russian by Alan Shuchat**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/978-0-387-48811-0), New York, NY: Springer (ISBN 0-387-36026-3/pbk; 0-387-048811-1/ebook). xx, 382 p. (2007). [ZBL1105.01009](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1105.01009).
- *Mashaal, Maurice*, Bourbaki: A secret society of mathematicians. Transl. from the French by Anna Pierrehumbert, Providence, RI: American Mathematical Society (AMS) (ISBN 0-8218-3967-5). 168 p. (2006). [ZBL1099.01022](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1099.01022).
- *Gillispie, Charles C.*, [**Science and Polity in France: The Revolutionary and Napoleonic Years**](https://books.google.com/books/about/Science_and_Polity_in_France.html?id=uNI3YgEACAAJ). Princeton University Press (2004).
- *Yandell, Benjamin H.*, The honors class. Hilbert’s problems and their solvers, Natick, MA: A K Peters. ix, 486 p. (2002). [ZBL0993.01001](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0993.01001).
- *Schweber, Silvan S.*, QED and the men who made it: Dyson, Feynman, Schwinger, and Tomonaga, Princeton Series in Physics. Princeton, NJ: Princeton University Press,. xxviii, 732 p. (1994). [ZBL0815.01011](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0815.01011).
- *Hunt, Bruce J.*, [**The Maxwellians**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Maxwellians). Cornell University Press (1991). [MR1260666](https://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1260666).
- *Grattan-Guinness, Ivor*, Convolutions in French mathematics, 1800-1840. Volume I: The settings. Volume II: The turns. Volume III: The data, Science Networks. Historical Studies. 2-4. Berlin: VEB Deutscher Verlag der Wissenschaften. Basel etc.: Birkhäuser, 1601 p. (1990). [ZBL0836.01013](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0836.01013).
- *Bell, E. T.*, Men of mathematics, XXI + 593 p. New York, Simon and Schuster (1937). [ZBL63.0793.03](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:63.0793.03).
- *Marie, Maximilien*, [**Histoire des sciences mathématiques et physiques**](https://archive.org/search.php?query=Maximilien%20Marie%20Histoire%20des%20sciences%20math%C3%A9matiques%20et%20physiques). Paris, Gauthier-Villars, 12 vol. (1883–1888).
- *Lord Brougham*, [**Lives of philosophers of the time of George III**](https://archive.org/details/livesofphilosoph00brourich). London, Glasgow, R. Griffin (1855).

Answer (score 1):

Let me add few items to the nice list of Francois: Koestler's biographies of Copernicus, Galileo and Kepler: Arthur Koestler, Sleepwalkers: History of Man's changing vision of the universe, multiple editions.

and F. Klein, History of mathematics in 19th century. (It is mostly about mathematics, but includes short biographies and some comparison of them).

and Michele Audin, "Fatou, Julia, Montel: the Great Prize of Mathematical Sciences of 1918 and beyond", also several editions.